# How to Write javascript running on the child page (PopUp.aspx) to update the value of a label on the parent page

Tags: javascript

any references document

Answer (score 5):

Here's how:

http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html

You'll have full access to any javascript methods in the parent opener simply by using

```
window.opener.myFunction(params);
```

Clarity EDIT:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('myLabel').value = 'some text';
```

Comment: Remember about ASP.Net's name mangling

Comment: Touche. Though there are several different ways to work around that. I'll wait for the next question on how to do that I suppose :)

Comment: I am trying on that way , but i got the error

Comment: What error? I know this works because I have a production website which does it.